# Batik copy element from one document to another

Tags: java, svg, batik

I'm trying to compose an svg with batik from elements from a source document. This works as long as the elements don't reference things defined in the defs section (like gradients or filters). But when a filter is referenced I get an exception. I tried to also copy over the defs section but that didn't help.

```
String parser = XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName();
SAXSVGDocumentFactory factory = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(parser);
Document source = factory.createDocument("source", getClass().getResourceAsStream("/artwork/source.svg"));

SVGOMDocument target = (SVGOMDocument) domImpl.createDocument(svgNS, "svg", null);
Node defs = source.getElementsByTagName("defs").item(0).cloneNode(true);
target.adoptNode(defs);
target.getRootElement().appendChild(defs);

BridgeContext ctx = new BridgeContext(new UserAgentAdapter());
GVTBuilder builder = new GVTBuilder();
builder.build(ctx, target);

Element sourceEl = getElementByXPath(source,
        "//*[@id='IMAGES']/*[@id='" + selection.getImageSet() + "']/*[@id='"
                + suit.abbreviation() + value + "-" + selection.getImageSet() + "']");
SVGOMElement complete = (SVGOMElement) sourceEl.cloneNode(true);
target.adoptNode(complete);
target.getDocumentElement().appendChild(complete);

Rectangle2D completeBBox = builder.build(ctx, complete).getSensitiveBounds();
```

The last line gives the exception. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

If I save the target svg after adding the defs section and then reload it again it works. But I would like to avoid this aditional step.

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: Caused by: org.apache.batik.bridge.BridgeException: null:-1
Cannot find the referenced element:
"#filter18051"

Comment: I guess you'll have to clone the referenced elements too. Or fix up the references to be remote references (assuming Batik supports remote references).

Comment: I did, they are defined in the defs section, and that is copied over completely (lines 6-9 in the code sample).

Comment: Perhaps adding the source doument would help us to help you.

Comment: The source document is quite long. But any document with a filter or gradient will reproduce the problem. As per my edit, it is clearly a case of batik not updating its internal structure when the defs section is added. Their should be a more batik specific way of adding it, but I can't find it.

Comment: Report it as a bug to Batik's bugtracker then.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to avoid the extra save/load. Use importNode instead of clone/adopt for the defs.

```
Node defs = target.importNode(source.getElementsByTagName("defs").item(0), true);
target.getRootElement().appendChild(defs);
```